# Scapy installation fails on osx with dnet import error

Tags: python, macos, installation, importerror, scapy

Having trouble installing Scapy and it's required dependancies. I have spent some time Googling for a solution but all 'solutions' seem to affect older versions of Python, or simply do not work.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import Queue
import time
from scapy.all import *

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread) :

    def __init__(self, queue, tid) :
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.tid = tid
        print 'Worker: %d' %self.tid

    def run(self) :
        total_ports = 0
        while True :
            port = 0
            try :
                port = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
            except Queue.Empty :
                print 'Worker %d exiting. %d ports scanned'  %(self.tid, total_ports)

                return

                #Scanning begins

            ip = sys.argv[1]
            response = sr1(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(dport=port, flags='S'), verbose=False, timeout=.2)


            if response :
                if response[TCP].flags == 18 :

                    print 'ThreadID: %d: Got port no. %d status: OPEN' %(self.tid, port)
                self.queue.task_done()
                total_ports += 1

queue = Queue.Queue()

threads = []
for i in range(1, 10) :
    print 'Creating WorkerThread : %d' %i
    worker = WorkerThread(queue, i)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    threads.append(worker)
    print 'WorkerThread %d created' %i

for j in range(1, 100) :
    queue.put(j)

queue.join()

for item in threads :
    item.join()

print 'Scanning complete'
```

Python version is 2.7.5 and path to Python verified.

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

When script is executed I am getting the following error:

```
./multi-threaded-scanner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multi-threaded-scanner.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from bsd import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bsd.py", line 12, in <module>
    from unix import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pcapdnet import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 160, in <module>
    import dnet
ImportError: No module named dnet
```

I can use both the Scapy and Python interactive interpreters and running `import scapy` in the Python interpreter produces no errors.
When the script was run initially the `pcapy` module was missing, however I installed that
and then the issue switched to dnet, which I cannot find a solution for.
[A similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430573/scapy-install-issues-nothing-seems-to-actually-be-installed), seems to describe the same issue but the workarounds have no effect.
Can anybody shed any more light on this issue?

Commands used to install pcapy and libdnet:

libdnet-1.11.tar.gz (01-19-2005)

```
` ~/Downloads/libdnet-1.11    
chmod a+x configure
 ~/Downloads/libdnet-1.11    
./configure  && make`
```

Exits successfully

Pcapy: Latest stable release (0.10.8), updated August 26, 2010

`~/Downloads/pcapy-0.10.8  

sudo python setup.py install
Password:
running install
running build
running build_ext
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/96pings.pcap to 777
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pcapytests.py to 777
running install_data
running install_egg_info
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pcapy-0.10.8-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pcapy-0.10.8-py2.7.egg-info
 ~/Downloads/pcapy-0.10.8  `

Results for compiling with new flags

```
 ~/Downloads/libdnet-1.12    
sudo CFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --prefix=/usr and archargs='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' make
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/Users/richardcurteis/Downloads/libdnet-1.12/config/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/richardcurteis/Downloads/libdnet-1.12/config/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `and': machine `and' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh config/config.sub and failed
 ~/Downloads/libdnet-1.12  
```

Comment: How have you installed `scapy` and `pcapy`? Which commands have you used? Were there any errors reported? Have you installed [`libdnet`](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: Added onto original post. All exit successfully and the script rerun in refreshed terminal but with the same error

Comment: What `OS` do you have?

Comment: OSX Mavericks

`System Version: OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## EDIT (30.10.19)

### Install *Scapy*

*Scapy*'s official documentation [lists](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) the possible bundles:

- Default, only *Scapy*:

  - `$ pip install scapy`
- Recommended, *Scapy* and [*iPython*](https://ipython.org):

  - `$ pip install --pre scapy[basic]`
- Complete, *Scapy* & all its main dependencies:

  - `$ pip install --pre scapy[complete]`

### Install optional dependencies

*Scapy* requires certain dependencies for some special features, such as for plotting, 2D & 3D graphics, [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy) decryption, [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) operations and [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) decryption, [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)) and [VOIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP). Most of these software are installable via [*pip*](https://pypi.org/project/pip). *Scapy*'s official documentation [presents](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#optional-dependencies) them along with some examples that test whether the installation was successful.

### Configure *libpcap* integration

*Scapy*'s official documentation [states](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x) that it works natively since the recent versions but it's possible to configure it to use [*libpcap*](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap), which may be installed using either [*Homebrew*](https://brew.sh) or [*MacPorts*](https://www.macports.org). Both installation methods work fine, yet *Homebrew* is used to run unit tests with [*Travis CI*](https://travis-ci.com/secdev/scapy). Note that *Libpcap* might already be installed, for example if [*tcpdump*](https://www.tcpdump.org) is installed, such as in the case of [*OSX*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pcap.3.html).

#### Install using *Homebrew*

```
$ brew update  # update Homebrew
$ brew install libpcap  # install libpcap
```

Enable it in *Scapy* via `from scapy.config import conf; conf.use_pcap = True`.

#### Install using *MacPorts*

```
$ sudo port -d selfupdate  # update MacPorts
$ sudo port install libpcap  # install libpcap
```

Enable it in *Scapy* via `from scapy.config import conf; conf.use_pcap = True`.

---

### EDIT (27.05.15)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385092/3903832) states that all mentioned issues were fixed, and provides a much simpler installation method. However, its comments suggest that although it seems to work on *OS X 10.10 Yosemite* and *OS X 10.11 El Capitan*, it might fail for certain other versions.

```
$ brew install libdnet --with-python
$ pip install pcapy
$ pip install scapy
```

If *Homebrew*'s `site-packages` is not in *Python*'s `sys.path` variable, the following should be executed (see [this](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) for more information), with the actual *username* replacing the placeholder <USERNAME>:

```
$ mkdir -p /Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

---

### The original answer

You have not completed the installation of [*libdnet*](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/) and its *Python* wrapper, as stated in [*Scapy*'s installation guide](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#install-from-original-sources):

```
$ wget https://github.com/dugsong/libdnet/archive/libdnet-1.12.tar.gz
$ tar xfz libdnet-1.12.tgz
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd python
$ python2.5 setup.py install
```

If your system is 64 bit, use these compilation commands instead:

```
$ CFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure
$ archargs='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' make
```

Moreover, please verify that you've installed the correct version, i.e. 1.12 rather than 1.11.

If that fails as well, try installing via *MacPorts* and use its `dnet.so` file, as described [here](http://www.r00tsec.com/2013/11/howto-install-scapy-in-mac-osx.html):

```
$ port selfupdate
$ port upgrade outdated
$ port install py27-libdnet
$ port install libdnet 
$ cp /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnet.so /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

That link also recommends changing some code in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py` (fix `OSError: Device not configured`).

Change line 34 from:

```
f=os.popen("netstat -rn") # -f inet
```

to:

```
f=os.popen("netstat -rn | grep -v vboxnet") # -f inet
```

as follows:

```
def read_routes():
    if scapy.arch.SOLARIS:
#       f=os.popen("netstat -rvn") # -f inet
        f=os.popen("netstat -rn | grep -v vboxnet") # -f inet
```

If you still get the error `OSError: Device not configured`, then try performing similar changes to the other branches of the `if` clause (specifically, to its `else` branch), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28015362/3903832).

Comment: Yeah I've run that too, again, exited fine but the same error on importing dnet

Comment: This seems to be the part that's going wrong.

`from pcapdnet import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 160, in <module>
    import dnet
ImportError: No module named dnet`

Comment: Getting a configure error, I've added the output to the original post.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. These are 2 separate commands, and I think the `prefix` flag is not required, so I removed it. Please check my updated post.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it, the script itself is blowing up in my face but the import errors are now gone.
Editing the `unix.py` and compiling with those flags appears to have solved it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

All issues mentioned above seem all fixed.  I'm running OS X Yosemite.  I got a working scapy by simply the following three commands.

```
brew install --with-python libdnet
pip install pcapy
pip install scapy
```

Comment: But missing dnet "ImportError: No module named dnet"

Comment: same here. how did you get rid of missing dnet error?

Comment: Still the dnet error, though. This answer should be voted down.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running OSX 10.5.9 - spent forever trying to get scapy working - after installing dnet/pcap libraries I got the "OSError:Device not configured" too.  Tried replacing line 34 in unix.py with

`"netstat -rn | grep -v vboxnet"`

Still got the same error.  But when I change line 37 instead in the "else" part of the if block:

```
def read_routes():
    if scapy.arch.SOLARIS:
        f=os.popen("netstat -rvn") # -f inet
    elif scapy.arch.FREEBSD:
        f=os.popen("netstat -rnW") # -W to handle long interface names
    else:
        # f=os.popen("netstat -rn") # -f inet
        f=os.popen("netstat -rn | grep -v vboxnet") # -f inet
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

(This is a comment to [Tim Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385092/6470939)'s Answer, but I'm missing the reputation to do so)

Keep in mind to do what brew is actually telling you:

> ==> Caveats
>   Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules this formula installed.
>   If you plan to develop with these modules, please run:  [...]

```
mkdir -p /Users/YourUsernameHere/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/YourUsernameHere/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

So just re-run the brew command and execute the two lines it's telling you there to use all installed brew python packages.

Comment: Note: remember to edit "YourUsernameHere" if you copy-paste the above script!

Answer (score 0):

In OSX El Capitan, what worked for me was to force pip to reinstall pcapy using sudo:
`sudo pip install --user pcapy -I`