# Installing Scapy on Yosemite

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, osx-yosemite, scapy

I am trying to run Scapy on my Macbook pro with OS Yosemite.

I installed it with the following command

```
brew install scapy
```

Everything looks ok but when I run

```
scapy
```

I get this errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scapy", line 25, in <module>
interact()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/main.py", line 278, in
interact
scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 25, in   <module>
from route import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 162, in <module>
conf.route=Route()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 22, in __init__
self.resync()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 31, in resync
self.routes = read_routes()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 86, in read_routes
ifaddr = scapy.arch.get_if_addr(netif)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 36, in get_if_addr
return socket.inet_ntoa(get_if_raw_addr(iff))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 201, in get_if_raw_addr
return i.get(ifname)["addr"].data
File "dnet.pyx", line 990, in dnet.intf.get
OSError: Device not configured`
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT: if I run

```
sudo scapy
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scapy", line 25, in <module>
interact()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/main.py", line 278, in interact
scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 25, in <module>
from route import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 162, in <module>
conf.route=Route()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 22, in __init__
self.resync()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 31, in resync
self.routes = read_routes()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 86, in read_routes
ifaddr = scapy.arch.get_if_addr(netif)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 36, in get_if_addr
return socket.inet_ntoa(get_if_raw_addr(iff))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 201, in get_if_raw_addr
return i.get(ifname)["addr"].data
KeyError: 'addr'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scapy installation fails on osx with dnet import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229057/scapy-installation-fails-on-osx-with-dnet-import-error)

Comment: It's still not working, same error. I've tried also with a fresh installation of scapy but nothing has changed

Comment: do you run scapy as root ?

Comment: I tried but it sitll returns error

Comment: Of course you took a look at [The homebrew scapy issues list](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/search?q=scapy+is%3Aissue&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a [known bug](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/149). Until they fix the problem you could try this:

In the file `scapy/arch/unix.py` add the `elif scapy.arch.DARWIN:` part:

```
def read_routes():
    if scapy.arch.SOLARIS:
        f=os.popen("netstat -rvn") # -f inet
    elif scapy.arch.FREEBSD:
        f=os.popen("netstat -rnW") # -W to handle long interface names
    elif scapy.arch.DARWIN:
        f = os.popen("netstat -rn | grep -v vboxnet")  # Fix OSX problem            
    else:
        f=os.popen("netstat -rn") # -f inet
    ok = 0
    mtu_present = False
```

If you have troubles to find the scapy location you can run

```
python -v
>>> import scapy
import scapy # directory /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy
```

[Reference](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/161)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with the 'addr' key error and worked it out (your first error will be permissions - so yes, you will need to sudo).

By editing the underlying Python code to get some debug info, I could see the interface being checked had no IP address set on it BUT the OS had an (old/manual) static route which made use of this unconfigured interface.

When dnet was loading/importing it was iterating through the routes and then checking the interfaces to get the IP (which it couldn't as I was no longer using it and therefore it had no IP).

Removed the static route and it worked fine.